# Why React component is not update when the props passed to it changes?

Tags: reactjs

```
function Greeting(props){     
    return <h1>{props.name}</h1>;
}  

var name = "Henok"; 

setTimeout( () => {name="Rahel";},2000);

ReactDOM.render(<Greeting name={name} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

> As far as I know React components update  life cycle hook when the
>   props passed to it modified or its state changed.

Even though I changed the name to Rahel, I couldn't see the message Rahel on the browser?

> If my assumption was wrong, in what situation does React component
>   update life cycle hook?

Comment: You're doing the "update" from outside the React ecosystem. There's nothing to force a child component re-render.

Comment: What Dave said is correct. To see how component life cycle works, you need to use stateful component. Check [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/8k2yy5v1m8).

Answer (score 0):

Hey you have the right idea, but the React way of doing it is a little different.

Try doing this instead:

```
import * as React from 'react'

function App(){
    const [name, setName] = React.useState('Henok')

    const changeName = () => setName('Rahel')

    React.useEffect(() => {
       setTimeout(() => {
          changeName()
       }, 2000);
    }, [])

    return <Greeting name={name} />
} 


function Greeting(props){     
    return <h1>{props.name}</h1>;
}  


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```